# creating a drive (letter) that is a link to a folder

Tags: windows-7, mount, symbolic-link, windows-command-prompt, command-line-interface

on my home pc I want to simplify things when it falls to accessing my home folder, so I would like to make my c:\Users\myusername folder pointing to a virtual drive created ad-hoc, such as Y:.
In this I would spare the tediousness of writing that long path every time I want some application I am writing to access some files in my home directory.

Any ideas on how to do it? A friend of mine once did that with a simple command, but it was probably at the times of MS-DOS. I wonder if that command got preserved during time till my Windows 7, and which command was that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `subst` here.